# 3NF synthesis reduction algorithm

Tags: database-design, functional-dependencies, third-normal-form

I am working for a DBMS class and came across 3NF synthesis algorithm here
http://cis.csuohio.edu/~matos/notes/cis-611/ClassNotes/13-3NF-Synthesis.html

I am stuck with canonical cover computation. The problem is as follows:
Reduce the following FD to 3NF:

```
FD1 : AB→C
FD2 : C→D
FD3 : D→B
FD4 : B→E
```

The canonical cover is

```
FD1 : A→C
FD2 : C→D
FD3 : D→B
FD4 : B→E
```

After computing, the relations are merged `{(A,C), (C,D), (D,B,E)}`. 
The synthesis algorithm is lossless, but from the method, isn't the FD1 from the question not satisfied?

Comment: I don't believe that A->C is part of the canonical cover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know Its late But canonical cover is
    A→B
    A→C
    B→D
    B→E
    A→F

so R1(ABCF) and R2(BDE)